# Adding hosts entry to argocd pod

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I have set up an argocd server inside a kubernetes cluster.
Also I setup a gitlab server outside the cluster.
I used a hosts entry to access the gitlab via gitlab.xxx

To get access to the Argocd server I used a NodePort.
When I try to add my repo I get this error.

```
argocd repo add git@gitlab.xxx:root/xxx.git --insecure-ignore-host-key --ssh-private-key-path /root/gitlab/git_key 
FATA[0000] rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error testing repository connectivity: dial tcp: lookup gitlab.xxx on 10.96.0.10:53: no such host
```

So I tried adding a host entry like this via the deployment YAML

```
hostAliases:
      - ip: "192.168.xxx.yyy"
        hostnames:
        - "gitlab.xxx"
```

After restarting I read out the hosts like this:

```
kubectl exec argocd-server-xxxxxxxxxxxxx -n argocd -- cat /etc/hosts
```

Output:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
172.16.113.139  argocd-server-xxxxxxxxx
```

Where did I go wrong to add the hosts entry to make the repository avaible?

EDIT:
Also tried editing the configmap of the coreDNS like this

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
                errors
        health {
            lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes homelab-k8s in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
          pods insecure
          fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
          prefer_udp
          max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30

        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
        hosts {
          192.168.178.XXX gitlab.XXX
          fallthrough
        }
    }
```

And restarted by deleting the pods, but still no connection over the hostname possible.